# Usage of "a" and matching plural or singular

Tags: grammatical-number

When I read a manual, I am little bit confused of using "a". Here's a confusing sentence.

"Depending on the parts to be treated and the required grinding results they represent **a** real alternative to standard rotary vibrators."

The sentence subject is plural. Why is "a" used when the sentence indicates real alternative and then following object is plural?

Thank you~

Comment: The plurality depends on the **head** of a noun phrase. The noun phrase is "A real alternative to standard rotary vibrators". The head is "alternative", which is singular so "A" is used.

Comment: Because they are treating "standard rotary vibrators" as [a collective noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun). Meanwhile, you're right; the sentence could very well have been "...they represent real alternatives..." or "...a real alternative to a standard rotary vibrator."